# Using google drive sdk, unable to upload a file: Response coming to null

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, file-upload, google-drive-api

I have a simple code below to upload to google drive but i get response = null everytime. My authentication works and I am able to list the files but not upload or create directory.
Do I need some extra permissions? I have seen some samples and I am following them but still my upload doesn't work.

It will be of great help if someone could correct me. Below is my upload code.

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File uploadFile(DriveService service, string uploadFile, string parent = null)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(uploadFile))
                {                
                    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
                    body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadFile);
                    body.Description = "File uploaded by installed app";
                    body.MimeType = GetMimeType(uploadFile);
                    //body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = parent } };

                    // File's content
                    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFile);
                    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

                    try
                    {
                        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(uploadFile));
                        //request.Convert = true;
                        request.Upload();
                        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File f = request.ResponseBody;
                        Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
                        return f;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + uploadFile);
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Need guidance on this, I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. I was not passing enough scopes but just DriveService.Scope.Drive. I changed from `string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };` to

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly,      
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,   
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly, 
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,      
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };
```

Comment: Can you give me more details on this fix? I am stuck on this

Comment: @ASD Just assign the scopes to all for now as shown above and see which one you need by removing one by one as per your need, if definition from the docs isn't clear. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files to Google Drive will require you to use the Drive REST API. Since you already have an authentication token, you'll just need to call the POST URL and other parameters that are needed to be set.

A simple upload case will look like this

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data
```

There are other `uploadType`s to choose from, so just pick up something that will benefit you the best. More information about Uploading files can be seen at the [V2 Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-uploads). A sample code is also provided in their [github repository](https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample) (though this is in JS).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have created a post request in this code above using the API. And I get response = null. I want to do it through code above. Any idea what am I doing wrong there?